# Entity Framework Error on creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I get the following error:

"ERROR: Unable to update Web.Config because of the following exception: 'The value contains embedded nulls (\u0000).
Parameter name: provider connection string'."

All I'm doing is adding a new model to my ASP.Net MVC app.....

Just to be clear, this is when the wizard creates the model from the DB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a bug in the wizard, when it happens you have to go in and modify the web.config by hand...

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging by your error message, the value of your connection string is invalid.

Have a read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx). If reading that doesn't help, please consider editing the question with the connection string - ensuring that no identifiable information is there.

Comment: Actually the Entity connection string never gets included in the web.config by the GUI... It just hands out that error message, I had to put in there by had.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you used a text editor which used an encoding scheme the provider doesn't like. Try re-editing it in VS and see if that fixes it.